# How to save a drive's partition to a file in Windows?

Tags: partitioning, partition-recovery, administration

I've got an usb drive with several partitions, ntfs, exfat and ext3. I would like to extract the ext3 partition to image.bin file to be independent. How could I do that in Windows?

Comment: I think you'll have better luck using linux to create the image, plain dd or a few gui tools. *Maybe* linux from inside a VM, if it can
directly read the usb

Comment: Yes I finally did it from inside a virtual machine, detecting the partition with fdisk and parted and then using pv or dd to copy the partition. On Windows there's cygwin, but unfortunately some partitions are not populated under /dev, probably because are not recognized by windows.

Proprietary tools like Acronis Disk Director or EaseUS Partition Master don't have the option for such a thing.

Comment: Guess I should make that an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the drive image from linux, with `dd` or some gui tools that can make images (like Disks / gnome-disk-utility).

Even while running windows, if you ran linux in a Virtual Machine and can directly read the USB drive, that should work.

I know there are some ext drivers available for Windows, I tried a few and some worked, some didn't. Just seeing multiple partitions on a USB drive was beyond some of the tools, I did not have very good luck.